# Why is disabled status 2 instead of 0?

Tags: stock, development, design, status

A question for any magento devs:

Why is it that an enabled product has status 1, while a disabled product has a status of 2? Usually, "enabled" or "active" or whatever gets the status 1, while the converse is 0. Is there a reason why magento uses 2 here instead?

Comment: Often wondered this myself, no idea though. It's presumably not a boolean value. Is there another state other than enabled or disabled?

Comment: @JamesAllwood Nope. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status defines STATUS_ENABLED and STATUS_DISABLED, nothing else.

Comment: Beautiful question, inadvertently helped answer something I was trying to figure out!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all the values shouldn't even be important.
Use in your code these constants `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED`.
The reason I found so far is that when you want to create a product, in most cases you want it to be enabled. If the value for status disabled was `0`, then this will be selected because the way that the current values are passed to the form through `$form->setValues($data)`.
When creating a product `$data` is empty and, in the case of dropdowns, 0 = empty.
**[EDIT]**
I just remembered something else.
Initially the status had a separate table and there were 3 possible values.

```
insert  into {$this->getTable('catalog_product_status')}(`status_id`,`status_code`) values (1,'Enabled'),(2,'Disabled'),(3,'Out-of-stock');
```

And you could add more. check `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-install-0.7.0.php`.
This approach was dropped in `mysql4-upgrade-0.7.4-0.7.5.php` and I guess that for compatibility they kept the ids of the statuses.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('catalog_product_status')};
```

Comment: "First of all the values shouldn't even be important." They are when you're creating a csv import file!

Comment: No they are not. You can just blindly take the values and use them in the import.

Comment: OK,  I think I understand your original point now. Let me rephrase - it's important to know what the values are when doing an import :) The fact that they are 1 & 2 is counter-intuitive. Would expect 0 & 1

Answer (score -1):

the product status value comes from the "status" select field from product management in admin. the "enabled" and "disabled" are the options of the select field with values 1 and 2.
these are not boolean values.